# Why not use an index when doing the same query in another database?

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have two database. 
one is prod database (mysql)
another one is development database (mysql)

when I use explain key, development database used index, 
but prod database is not work.

same query
same database (development database is copy of prod)
same index .....

so i checked index, 'show index' ...

but same index.

**explain result of development database**
[image]

**explain result of prod database**
[image]

I expect 'p' table to use index 'idx_payment_tb'

Comment: If you could, include some of sample data and your original query. I recently been working with indexes myself and I found out that index is used mostly on `WHERE` operator. A few of my front end colleague was complaining that some of their operation took extremely long to load. when I inspect the query, some of the fields in `WHERE` operator is not indexed. So I've created index for every fields in there and when I compare my `EXPLAIN`, I did find some improvement.

Comment: a "copy of prod", particularly a recent one, very likely means that the statistics are much "fresher" than the prod db, and possibly that the indexes are not as fragmented either.  It is very difficult to draw conclusions with very limited information.

Answer (score 0):

When the Optimizer chooses not to use an index, it is often for a good reason -- namely that the data distribution is such that using the index would actually be slower.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` as text, not images.  There are many reasons why an index might be shunned by the Optimizer; we can probably tell you which reason was used this time.

- If it is a tiny table, why bother with the index.
- If there key being used occurs "a lot" in the table (which might be different between your dev and prod), the bouncing back and forth between the index and the data is likely to be slower.
- The statistics could be different between the two machines.